# Log4net event log full

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using log4net event log appender to log to event viewer and after I am getting the following exception:

> Unable to write to event log using source source name Win32exception
>   event log is full.

```xml
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
          <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR"/>
          </filter>
          <!--The name of the application-->
          <applicationName value="eventsource"/>
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
          </layout>
    </appender>
```

Could you please let me know what will be the workaround for this?
Thanks,
Ajai

Comment: Have you tried...clearing the log?

Comment: i want something that will automatically done in log4net.... like if event log is full it will write to the disk and clear the event log.. i should able to configure the name of the file to back up data in the log4net appender

Answer (score 2):

Right click the event name,go to properties ..check the appropriate option for "When maximum event log size is reached...

Answer (score 0):

The error should be clear enough, your event log is full - so you gotta do something about that.

Either increase the size of your event log, or delete/clean up old events,

See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fn_fulllog.mspx?mfr=true and http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/fixing-the-event-log-is-full-error-on-windows-xp/

Comment: i want something that will automatically done in log4net.... like if event log is full it will write to the disk and clear the event log.. i should able to configure the name of the file to back up data in the log4net appender